# PHP DateTime timestamps are not correct

Tags: php, date, timezone

I have a timestamp which I am trying to convert to another timezone. I need to take DST in to account when doing so.

The code I am using is below:

```
    $date = new DateTime("@".$timestamp); 

    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\r\n";

    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));   
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\r\n";  // Pacific time

    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Athens'));
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\r\n";  // Berlin time
```

The output (which is correct) is:

```
 2014-01-30 20:24:48
 2014-01-30 21:24:48
 2014-01-30 22:24:48
```

However if I change the format to "U" which is the value used in Date() to get timestamps the following is output:

```
1391113488
1391113488
1391113488
```

Why are the timestamps not coming out with the timezone offset applied to them?

Comment: Unix timestamps are always in UTC

Comment: Because they're coming out as Unix timestamps (that's what `U` format gives) which don't have a timezone but are UTC

Comment: The definition of a UNIX timestamp: seconds since midnight Jan. 1st 1970 UTC. How would timezones figure into this definition‽

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTime::getOffset` will give you the offset in seconds and `DateTime::getTimestamp` will give you the **Unix timestamp which is always UTC** (gives you the same like `$datetime->format('U')`).

So in order to get a "timestamp" with the offset do this:

```
$timestampWithOffset = $date->getTimestamp() + $date->getOffset();
```

Comment: That's not a UNIX timestamp anymore though and therefore rather useless.

Comment: No it's not necessarily useless. It depends on your use case.

Comment: @sjkm: can you provide example where this could be useful?

Comment: This was an option I was going to take, but does the offset take DTC in to account?

Comment: Unless you also know what the offset was and you include this in your calculation when reverse-calculating the "timestamp" to a human readable time, the timestamp won't be correct. You should really save the timestamp as is and additionally store the specific timezone you want it displayed in, something you need to do anyway.